# html javascript doesn't work or show an alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm using javascript to validate my html (checking if the user input a correct data ) source code and it's more than simple but the problem is that when i press the submit button i can't see any result or alert

```
<script type= "text/javascript">

    function checkname()
    {
        name = document.getElementById("myname");
        var reg= /^[A-Z][a-z]+$/
        if (!name.value.match(reg))
        {
            alert("Please enter your name begin with a CAPITAL letter");
            return false;
        }


        if ( name.value=="")
        {
            alert("you kindly forget to put your name here");
            return false;
        }
        return name.value("Welcome" + name + " to valet parking service VPS");
    }

    </script>
```

that's all for the first part where the script is written now in the html tag where the button is typed

```
<input type="submit" value=" submit " >
```

and that's what written in the form

```
<form  onsubmit = " checkname(); return false; ">
```

Comment: What do you mean by "validate my html source code"?

Comment: and btw, you are never binding the `checkname()` function to the submit button, so it's quite obvious it won't work. Moreover, you have a unconditional `return true;` in the middle of your function, so the rest is never executed.

Comment: use tool like firebug or chrome devel tool to see what js error you have.

Comment: Both your title and your description are very vague. Please edit your question so the title and description explicitly pertain to your problem.

Comment: @Jason corrected i mean am using the html just to check if the user input a correct data but the problem is that i can't see any alert so there is something wrong written if you know can you please help 
thanks a lot

Comment: @user3829242 Instead of using pure javascript, I recommend use jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the mistake (you always return false to the submit function):

```
<form  onsubmit = " checkname(); return false; ">
```

Try this:

```
<form onsubmit="return checkname();">
```

Then modify your checkname function to something like this:

```
function checkname()
{
    var name = document.getElementById("myname");
    var reg= /^[A-Z][a-z]+$/
    if (!name.value.match(reg))
    {
        alert("Please enter your name begin with a CAPITAL letter");
        return false;
    }

    if ( name.value=="")
    {
        alert("you kindly forget to put your name here");
        return false;
    }

    name.value("Welcome" + name + " to valet parking service VPS");

    return true;
}
```

Comment: but still it didn't work there is no alert notification

Answer (score 0):

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/267wL/

**HTML**

```
<form action="demo.html" id="myForm" onsubmit = "checkname(); return false; " method="post">
    <p>
        <label>First name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="myname" />
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value=" submit "/>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function checkname()
{
    var name = document.getElementById("myname");
    var reg= /^[A-Z][a-z]+$/;
    if (!name.value.match(reg))
    {
        alert("Please enter your name begin with a CAPITAL letter");
        return false;
    }
    name.value = "Welcome " + name.value + " to valet parking service VPS";

    return false;
}
```

You don't have to check null values. If the `name.value` is empty, your regex validation failed.

Pay also attention that the welcome message is set in the input text. Weird behaviour...

Comment: still there is no alert notification

Comment: Did you test the JSFiddle link? Everything is OK, the problem must be relative to your JavaScript code

Answer (score 0):

The return true; will block all following code.

Comment: i did it and still i have no alert notification it's more than weird and i can't solve it

Comment: @mba3gar Try putting an else and alert: if (name.value == "") {...} else {alert(name.value);}. When still no alert, I'm afraid the checkName() is not invoked at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<script>   function checkname() {
var x = document.forms["myForm"]["myname"].value;
if (x==null || x=="") {
    alert("First name must be filled out");
    return false;
}
```

}

```
   <form    name='myForm' action='action.php' onsubmit='return checkname()' method='post'>
First name: <input type="text" name="myname"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>
```